# Corona vs Titanium for iOS and Android development

Tags: android, ios, lua, titanium, coronasdk

i am using phonegap since last one year but not satisfied with the performance, now i m looking for a change and wanna start with Corona or Titanium but don't know which one is better, i don't have any problem with Corona's Lua or Titanium's JS just want a better and scalable working environment, please show me the light to chose a better way.

Answer (score 3):

In general these kinds of tools just doesn't work optimal. Applications made tend to crash, leak memory and you still have to do a lot of double work for making specific solutions for iOS and Android... not recommended.

**Edit**

Of course they have their use but Facebook abandoned this approach after a lot of issues. There is a lesson to be learned when a huge company like Facebook throws the towel in the ring.

Answer (score 1):

Corona is mainly for game development and titanium having one module for game development. If you focusing on game development than corona there for you otherwise use titanium.

Comment: is it not possible to develop a twitter or facebook like app with corona?

Comment: i have not deal with corona, just i have seen some basic demos and docs of corona. But i can say that you can develop that type of app in titanium.

Answer (score 1):

Titanium is perfect for facebook/twitter application development. They even have modules for it. The facebook one is for free, the twitter module comes with the premium version.

Facebook module documentation: http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Facebook-module

It's all build on JavaScript. So if you have any knowledge on it, you get the hang of it quite soon.