# Disadvantage/Advantage using Tabris against PhoneGap or Titanium or Corona

Tags: cordova, titanium, coronasdk, tabris

I was reading this article: http://www.infoq.com/articles/tabris 
and thinking about the benefits about using tabris in contrast 
to html-based tools like 
Phonegap http://phonegap.com/.

Is there also a comparison for Tabris, Corona, Titanium and PhoneGap?
like mentioned here:

 [What are the advantages and disadvantages of using Phonegap and Titanium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437690/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-phonegap-and-titanium) 
 or here 
[Corona vs Titanium for iOS and Android development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061710/corona-vs-titanium-for-ios-and-android-development)

As far as I know, I would use Tabris, if I have an application that uses lots of traffic (if there's much communication between client and server). 

PhoneGap I would use, if it's faster to develop a mobile application and the limited features given through Html/JavaScript is sufficient.

What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

Tabris will perform better in all areas comparing to cordova/phonegap, or any tool that will rely on webview.
Not only uses the native components, will have better memory management and battery life .
I am fairly new to Tabris but I am rewriting one app with it and the benefits are great.

Answer (score 1):

I'm experienced with PhoneGap but not with Tabris or Corona.

PhoneGap 3.x actually has a LOT of plugins enabling developers access to the native device's APIs. I looked at the Tabris [site](http://developer.eclipsesource.com/) and it looks like it is essentially developing a server with a cross-platform UI. That means an app developed with Tabris would be unable to do a lot of things that PhoneGap can do. See a list of PhoneGap plugins [here](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins).

If all you need is a UI with server side code, then Tabris sounds great. For anything else I'd go with PhoneGap. (Again, not experienced with Corona at all)

UPDATE: I looked at Corona and the free version is likely equivalent to PhoneGap, except written in Lua, and the paid versions seem to be quite more powerful than any of the others.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried both, PhoneGap and Tabris. For me, the main disadvantage of Tabris in comparison with PhoneGap is, that you cannot directly control the client side, e.g. for validating user interaction before pushing data to the server.

With PhoneGap, you have a lot of freedom by using JavaScipt on the client-side. With Tabris you are bound the given set of specific listeners for any RWT element. But there's to say that there are not only listeners for UI-Elements, but also for example the GeolocationListener, the ProgressListener for Browser, and much more listeners that do not require directly user interaction such as pushing a button.

Due to my experience with PhoneGap, I actually had an idea for a hack inside my Tabris Application. I wanted to integrate a Map, draw GPS-tracks on it and let the user interact without the need to contact the server for every interaction. Therefore I created a page, that only shows a Browser (without address- and titlebar). The user does not recognize that he is just interacting with a browser inside the Tabris-App. I've added a GeolocationListener that determines the current position and also watches, so when the user changes his position, the server is being notified. The actual hack is, that you can implement a JavaScript API and call JS-functions from serverside (!!). The other way, that you call a Java-Method from clientside JavaScript, like in "normal" SWT is not supported by Tabris. The execute() method executes JavaScript on the client side.

That's the code snippet shows my implementation of the Tabris page, "bikeNavigatorMap" is the instance of the JavaScript API-object: http://pastebin.com/Lnb4EspC

So I've created a semi-hybrid app with Tabris. :)

Comment: You are using Tabris (remote) that is based on RAP/SWT. You have a point that Tabris (remote) executes all of the application logic on the server-side and thus provides no possibility to let a client execute input validation before sending data to the server. Tabris-js instead executes everything on the device (i.e. locally) and does not require a server at all. Both are different technologies. The original question is not clear about the targeted variant of "Tabris" - remote vs. JS.